# How to create a dataframe from previous dataframe with varied schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

```
df1=id:string,date:string
```

I want to create a `df2` from `df1` with schema
`id:int,date:date` with all the values from `df1` but with custom schema applied on `df2`.
Note:It should be generic as I am populating `df1` dynamically from rest api.

Comment: So you need to be able to create the schema given a string?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the columns to create a new DataFrame. This should be generic enough.

```
val df2 = df1.select('id.cast("Int"),to_date('date,dateFormat))
```